# Design a two-tape deterministic Turing machine M that recognizes the language L3= {x#(0^k) #y : x, y ∈ {0, 1}* , x = y ∧ |x| = k}

Tags: turing-machines, time-complexity, finite-automata

I'm having a hard time trying to write a two tape Turing machine

I wanted to first think Oh all I'd have to do is scan from left-to-right till I find the strings that matches the  accepted strings) but I'm stuck now and don't know how to continue

(Note** Σ = {0, 1, #} but the # character is only allowed as a marker to divide the input string
w into thirds. The M should run in O(n) time where n = |w|; and any accepted string gives n = 3k + 2 with k as above.)